# Getting zeros every time while using random function in Python

Tags: python

I am doing this as shown below.  Initially I have a 2D array A = [(1,2,3) , (4,5,6)]. Now through a function func , I want to replace all the elements in both the two rows of array A by random numbers. I am trying but I am getting every element as 0 after execution of the function. Can somebody help. Remember I have to do this problem by using this function func and doing these slicing operations.

```
import numpy as np
import random
A=np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
def func(B):
    B[0:3]= np.random.random((1,3))
    return(B)
                    
for ic in range(0,2):
    A[ic,:]= func(A[ic,:])

print(A)
```

```
Output
Everytime I am getting zeros. There should be random numbers in both the rows of array A . I think the random number generator is generating zeros every time. Can somebody help ??
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: `A`'s `dtype` is `int64`, so it can only hold integer values; `np.random.random((1,3))` generates 3 floats all less than 1, since its size is `(1,3)`. So, all the float values are getting truncated to zero because integers can't hold values between zero and one. Did you mean to maybe use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are constructing the array `A` is such that it will always have integer [dtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html). You can check with `print(A.dtype)`. This means that values that are between 0-1 are getting cast to zero which is a problem because `np.random.rand` only returns values between 0 and 1. You can fix this in a few ways:

1. Construct using floats
   `A=np.array([(1.,2.,3.),(4.,5.,6.)])`
2. Set dtype explicitly
   `A=np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], dtype=np.float)`
3. cast to float type
   `A=np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]).astype(np.float)`

Comment: Didn't see that you'd posted almost exactly the same thing when I was writing mine (on mobile). Nice work!

Comment: I've been doing this for too long :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `A` is an array of integers, and `np.random.random` generates floats that are less than one for practical purposes. Casting such a number to integer always yields zero.

You can fix in one of two ways:

1. Make `A` an array of `float` dtype:

   a. `A = np.array([[1.0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`
   b. `A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=float)`
   c. etc...
2. Generate random integers instead of floats, or at least floats that would cast to nonzero integers:

   a. `B[:]= np.random.randint(256, size=B.shape)`
   b. `B[:]= np.random.random(B.shape) * 256`
   c. etc...

Comment: I deleted my answer since yours is much more informative. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

your code with small modifications

```
import numpy as np
from random import random
A=np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)])
def func(B):
    B[0:3]= np.random.choice((1,3))
    return(B)
                
for ic in range(0,2):
A[ic,:]= func(A[ic,:])

print(A)
```

Instead of np.random.random you can use np.random.choice, it will generate random numbers

Comment: Thanks very much